# How to convert a File Blob to NSData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, nsdata

I have a problem converting a File Blob comming from a Webservice to an NSData Object. The File Blob can be any type of file. I can request a file from a Webserver via RestKit and get the following response:

```
[{
   "FileBlob":    [
      65,
      108,
      108,
      111,
      99,
      46,
      32,
      83,
      /* more integer values omitted */
   ],
   "FileID": 1234567890,
   "FileName": "name.txt"
}]
```

I convert the Response into a Dictionary via JSONKit `NSDictionary *dict = [[response bodyAsString] objectFromJSONString];` which works fine. But i cannot figure out how to convert the FileBlob into a NSData Object so that i can write it as a file onto the HDD. In case of a txt-File like in the example above i can go trough the array and convert all integer Values to chars

```
NSMutableString *fileString = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSNumber *value in [[dict valueForKey:@"FileBlob"] objectAtIndex:0]) {
    [fileString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value.integerValue];
}
```

and then save everything to disk

```
NSData *data = [fileString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *file = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];        
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:file contents:data attributes:nil];
```

But if the file is something else like a pdf this does not work. Is there anything i can do, to convert the File Blob to an NSData Object or anything else to write the blob as a file onto the disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) instead:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:blobs.count];

for (NSNumber *number in blobs)
{
    uint8_t byte = (uint8_t)[number intValue];
    [data appendBytes:&byte length:1];
}

// write data to file
```