# Convert from BLOB (FMDB result) to NSData Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, nsdata, fmdb

In my former app the data is read from disc like this:

```
NSData* image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngImage];
```

I am moving all the `.png` data as `BLOB` into a `SQLite` database which I query

```
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:pathToDatabase];
[database open];
NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT ....";
FMResultSet *resultFromDatabase = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
```

How do I convert the return (`BLOB`) from the database to an `NSData` Object?

Answer (score 0):

FMDB provides a [method](https://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/dataForColumn:) for this:

```
    NSData *image = [databaseResult dataForColumn:@"image_column"];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can convert BLOB to NSData:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:blobs.count];

for (NSNumber *number in blobs)
{
    uint8_t byte = (uint8_t)[number intValue];
    [data appendBytes:&byte length:1];
}
```

Comment: Simply copy & pasted from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556170/how-to-convert-a-file-blob-to-nsdata.